# Sending signed data from web3

Tags: web3js, nodejs, infura

So I'm only using Infura and web3 here, no local node running and I want to use functions like :

mycontract.methods.function(msg).send({from: address, gas: 200000})

it won't work because it is a state changing transaction, so I need to sign.

so I have:

var signed_data = web3.eth.accounts.sign(web3.utils.fromAscii("A20160528"), private_key);

and it return to me:

{ message: '0x413230313630353238',
  messageHash: '0x0a30d111fed6dbde69984b1763cde3f45838c870df0132da723731d3ea1c7225',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0xd36db528de6bc8ba97c8dffa27fe94288af53f26b82eb5acc6983a849db99902',

s: '0x69b3e6e8ddc69eeda0774bab2801b724f7dfa9cbfed60b4fa70637d420b91b05',
  signature: '0xd36db528de6bc8ba97c8dffa27fe94288af53f26b82eb5acc6983a849db9990269b3e6e8ddc69eeda0774bab2
801b724f7dfa9cbfed60b4fa70637d420b91b051b' }

How should I pass this to the web3 function such as :

mycontract.methods.function(msg).send({from: address, gas: 200000})

what should I put into msg variable?

Comment: what version of Web3? 1.0.0 or the 0.x?

Comment: the version is 1.0.0

Comment: But I'm not using truffle here

Comment: have a look at [sendSignedTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction)